# 2 overloaded operator>> methods gets called

Tags: c++

I have a Complex class with two overloaded `operator>>` methods, one for `std::istream` from console, second  one for `std::ifstream`.

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Complex& c) 
{

    int re, im;
    std::cout << "input the real-part of the complex" << std::endl;
    while ( ! (is >> re))
    {
        std::cout << "Please give me a double!  Try again: \n";
        is.clear();
        is.ignore(1000, '\n');
    }
    std::cout << "input the imaginary-part of the complex" << std::endl;
    while ( ! (is >> im))
    {
        std::cout << "Please give me a double!  Try again: \n";
        is.clear();
        is.ignore(1000, '\n');
    }
    c = Complex(re, im);
    return is;
}

std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream& ifs, Complex& c) 
{
    int re, im;
    ifs >> re; ifs>> im;
    c = Complex(re,im);
    return ifs;
}
```

In my program, I'm able to insert array of complex numbers from console or file. To simplify inserting, I've created additional method:

```
void insertArray(std::istream& is, Complex* arr, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        is >> arr[i];
    }
}
```

Unfortunatelly I've noticed that when this method is called with `std::ifstream` object as an argument,

```
std::ifstream ifs("complex.dat");
insertArray(ifs, x, size);
```

both operator>> methods are called so the console contains additional output however data is properly loaded from file. The result presented in the image. 
[image: console output]

It's easy to notice that program asks for given value as for console buffer howver loads data from file buffer.

Is there any way to handle it except crating separate method `insertArray2` with `std::ifstream` instead of `std::istream`?

Comment: Any particular reason you have both overloads in the first place?

Comment: It doesn't look like *both* overloads are called, only the one for `std::istream`, which makes sense because inside `insertArray`, `is` is `std::istream&`.

Comment: I discourage implementing this operator twice. What if I use your class and want to read it from the console but provide my own messages? I can't, it will always use yours.

Comment: To be honest: no...
The Complex class was provided by the supervisor and I'm supposed to use it while doing my assignment. Probably he wanted to provide "user-friendly" requests for data in case of console input, which are not necessary when using `std::ifstream`

Comment: Why ignore 1000 characters and not all characters? There is a special constant you can use for that, can't remember off the top of my head.

Comment: Note that `std::cin` can be redirected from a file, but I guess that's not what your supervisor anticipated.

Comment: @0x499602D2: Both operators are called as array gets filled with data from file

Comment: I would suggest just changing the ifstream version's header to take an istream, and then just use a free function for what the istream version is doing. Having the extraction operator write to standard output violates the principle of least astonishment. Though, if you're stuck with these implementations, you can't really do anything about that...

Comment: I don't see how both gets called. What is the indication? As a fix you can make one operator for `std::istream&` and check if the address is the address of `std::cin` (i.e `if (&is == &std::cin)`).

Comment: This is calling the istream version because your insertArray function takes an istream. Overload resolution happens at compile time, so you get the istream version. Why do you think it's calling both?

Comment: Oh, my bad, I believe I've misunderstood obtained results. Thanks for making it clear!

Comment: Um  , so what you are really asking is: "In my function that takes `std::istream &`, how can I write something like `cout << foo` but only output if the input was `cin`" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider templating `insertArray`:

```
template<class T>
void insertArray(T& is, Complex* arr, int size)
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you could write:

```
if ( &is == &std::cin )
    std::cout << "Please give me a double!  Try again: \n";
```

which would generate this output only if the function was called with `std::cin`.  It wouldn't do that if you were using the function on a different `fstream` or `sstream` or whatever.